# How to install all Visual Studio 2010 templates

Tags: visual-studio-2010

One of my PC has VS2010 ultimate installed and it has all project templates. My the other PC has VS2010 professional installed and has fewer templates. I was wondering if it's possible to manually download those templates. I didn't find on msdn ([link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky.aspx) [link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fyc0azh.aspx)). Can the community advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File -> New Project

in the popup window you will see options for downloading online templates.
[image]